# Missing Items from Start Menu

Tags: windows-7, start-menu

I used to be able to search/open items from my start menu, but recently items have gone "missing".

Example: I used to be able to hit the start menu, type "iis" and the top item would be iis manager and I could open and run ... now I get a list of items that are not IIS

The same is true with typing "servi" - previously i would get Services (i.e. open local services), now it isn't showing

I've checked the properties on Customise Start Menu for "Search other files and libraries" and it is selected as "Search without public folders" ... is there something else that is happening?  It seems like something has changed, but I can determine what/how to revert to what it was.

Comment: HAve you added some items into the menu which are taking the shortcuts? I have had that happen.

Comment: Not that I can see, I've not done any installations since the change

Answer (score 1):

The symptom suggests the "Search programs and Control Panel" option is unchecked.  Right click on the Start button, select Properties, select the Start Menu tab, click Customize button, then scroll to "Search programs and Control Panel" and make sure it's checked.

Comment: it seems to be checked, though if i wait long enough i do see "services.exe" with the "default application icon" in the list (as opposed to "just services with the services icon") ... of course when i click on it it doesn't open the services panel though